# AppInventor: How can I persist the changed view/focus of the scrollable SVG via a userscript?

Tags: javascript, svg, scrollview, userscripts, app-inventor

I am currently able to change the view of the [app inventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/) scrollable SVG (where all the blocks are) by updating the `blocklyBlockCanvas` and `blocklyBubbleCanvas` elements with the following code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blocklyBlockCanvas")[0].setAttribute("transform", `translate(-${number1}, -${number2}) scale(1)`);
document.getElementsByClassName("blocklyBubbleCanvas")[0].setAttribute("transform", `translate(-${number1}, -${number2}) scale(1)`);
```

However, as soon as I click on the SVG, it jumps back to the previous view. I think I need to update the x and y attributes of this pattern element as they change when I scroll the svg (XXXXXXXXXXXX replaces a long number that is changed on each page reload):

```
<pattern id="blocklyGridPatternXXXXXXXXXXXX" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20" x="1356.7352240258992" y="-128.4999999999999">
```

But even if manually update the x and y attributes in the console, they are reset whenever I scroll the SVG.

So how to persist the changed view of the SVG?

The full userscript is here: https://pastebin.com/FC5wYcMb

Comment: (tip: `document.body.appendChild(a); document.body.appendChild(b)` can be written as `document.body.append(a, b)`)

Comment: Why should changes to the `transform` attribute persist? If you drag in the canvas the property *should* be updated in order to navigate through blocks.

Comment: @double-beep, Thanks for your tip! Maybe "persist" isn't the right verb. What I want to do is to find a particular block to modify it. I am able to bring this block into view by modifying `blocklyBubbleCanvas` and `blocklyBubbleCanvas`. But as soon as I click, zoom or drag the main svg, the view is reset to where it was before so I can't actually modify the desired block.  What I mean by persist is that when I click, zoom, or drag the main svg, then the desired block remains in the view.

Comment: @double-beep, also, sorry, I didn't paste the correct userscript in the pastebin. The link is now updated.